# ADO.Net SQL pooling in asp.net-mvc-4 application

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to optimize the sql connection in my wep application its create in .net mvc 4, i read that ado.net automatically manager the connection pooling but i'm some lost respect how exactly implement that, is correct if i create a global object with the connection in the Application_Start class then pass the connection object through all data object in my application ? something like this

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
...
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Connection String...");
DAOPeople daoPeople = new DAOPeople(conn);
...
}
```

in that way i avoided create a new SqlConnection for each dao, is correct?

Comment: No its not. Create (and close) you connection in the methods only when you need it.

Answer (score 3):

No, don't do that. You'll end up with a bottleneck at your connection object, as that single connection is shared across all sessions and requests to your app.

For connection pooling, you do the exact opposite: **don't** try to share or re-use a single connection object; **do** just create a *new* `SqlConnection` every time you need it, open it on the spot, and make sure it's disposed as soon as you're done via a `using` block. Even though your code looks like you're opening and closing a lot of connections, the connection pooling feature is *built in* and ensures you keep drawing from a small number of existing connections in the same pool.

That said, if you're on a *really* large site, you can do a little better. One thing large sites will do to help scale is avoid unnecessary memory allocations, and there is some memory that goes with creating an `SqlConnection` object. Instead they might, for example, have one main `SqlConnection` per HTTP request, with the possibility of either enabling [MARS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h32h3abf(v=vs.110).aspx) or having an additional secondary connection object in the request so they can run some things asynchronously. But this is only something the top 0.1% need to care about, and if you're at this level you're measuring to find out where the proper balance is for your particular site and load.